# How do you resume one workflow from another process in windows workflow foundation?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have an application that uses Windows Workflow and I am trying to write a service that will periodicly reload the workflows and check whether they have changed state based upon time events (DelayActivity).

Any ideas how to do this?

I thought it would be simple and straight forward but I can't get it to work quite right and I have tried multiple things.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The persistence service, which manages the out of box DelayActivity, will auto resume persisted workflows. And any changes to the workflow should be done thru the workflow itself, not out-of-band.